# How to send an embedded image in email from excel

Tags: excel, outlook

I would like to send a Excel chart in the body of an email (Outlook) (not as attachment) from VB, anyone know how to do this?

Solved:
Just to add a bit more detail to answer below
you'll need the following (could do with some improvement).

```
Sheets(2).ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export "C:\temp\Chart2.png"
```

....

```
   .HTMLBody = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'" & _
            "xmlns: x = 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel'" & _
            "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'> " & _
            "<head></head><body><img src='Chart2.png'></body></html>"
```

and

```
    .Attachments.Add ("C:\temp\Chart2.png")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like the best way is to **export the chart**:

```
Sheets(1).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Export "C:\Chart1.png"
```

And then **add the image** into your mail **HTML body**:

```
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "< img src='c:\folder\filename.png'>"
```

Confirmed by both [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/excel/thread/6fc76ceb-6642-4f71-ba41-b0b438d36de9) and [mrexcel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=562877)

Comment: Thanks spent about 2 days looking for a solution.

Comment: @JMax. This worked like a charm when I tried sending the image to my own outlook address, but when I tried forwarding the same mail with the embedded image to my colleagues, they were unable to see the image. The same thing happened when I tried forwarding it to my gmail account. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: @123apd when forwarding an email in Outlook, you have to manually confirm you want to download the image (try to do it by hand first and then automatize)

Answer (score 5):

I thought I'd add my solution here in addition to the one above since it is using both a sub and a temporary file path, in case you are interested.

I changed the code from [here](http://vba-useful.blogspot.fr/2014/01/send-html-email-with-embedded-images.html) to insert a chart using a temporary path (they do the same thing using a range of cells in the workbook):

```
Sub createGraph(nameSheet As String, nameChart As String, nameFile As String)
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
  Worksheets(nameSheet).Activate
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(nameSheet).ChartObjects(nameChart)
    .Activate
    .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".jpg", "JPG"
  End With
End Sub
```

In the HTML body put:

```
Call createGraph("Graphs", "Chart 1", "filename")
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
.Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "filename.jpg", olByValue, 0
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<img src='cid:filename.jpg'>"
```

By using "olByValue, 0" the attachment is added at position 0 and not visible in the email as an attachment.