# Substitute text in HTMLbody (Creating email from Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, email

I've got the following VBA code to properly create an email using an email template, however I'm trying to change some text in the email body using the `Substitute()` function. I'm receiving an error and am unsure on how to resolve this, any help would be great!

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Unable to get the Substitute property of the WorksheetFunction class

Here's the code attempting to create the email from my template...

```
Public Function GenerateEmail(fileName As String)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(fileName)

    With OutMail
        .HTMLbody = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(OutMail.HTMLbody, "%TESTNUM%", "98541")
        .Attachments.Add (Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
        .Display
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: I'm more curious as to why you are receiving that error but you have insufficient information to make a detmination.

Comment: @Jeeped I had got most of this code from another question and the person helping me disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `Replace`

```
.HTMLbody = Replace(OutMail.HTMLbody, "%TESTNUM%", "98541")
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, I was stuck on that for too long... Thanks a ton!

Comment: Would it be at all possible to replace `"%TESTNUM%"` with a range of say A3:B7 as a graph? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281016/how-to-send-an-embedded-image-in-email-from-excel

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, wish I could give double the answer rep for this

Comment: I just realized that creates an image, I'd like to create an actual chart... Reason being is when I search my sent inbox for a particular number it will come up listed in there as well. Is there a way without using an image?

Comment: No way that I can think of. You would have to somehow convert it to `html`. It may be possible, but very complex. Perhaps try asking an additional question. Maybe someone else knows a way, and this is getting off topic.

Comment: Yea you're right, well thanks again for everything braX!

Answer (score 2):

`Replace` is the correct way to go here as answered by @Brax.

---

> For anyone looking to understand the reason behind this error.

Just to explain why the 1004 happened with substitute, you need to check the parameters when using `WorksheetFunction`.

Here the issue is the allowed number of characters in a Excel cell. You can only put `32767` characters in the cell. Now, certainly, your HTMLBody has more characters in it, hence the error.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim validString     As String
    Dim inValidString   As String

    validString = "a" & Space(32766)
    inValidString = "b" & Space(32767)


    '/ Works as the string length is valid cell length : < =32767
    MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Substitute(validString, "a", "b")

    '/ Fails as the string length is invalid in terms of cell length : >32767
    MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Substitute(inValidString, "a", "b")

End Sub
```

Comment: Good to know! Learn something new every day.

Comment: Wow that's great information, appreciate the explanation of the error too!